# Getting OutOfMemoryError while uploading file to server

Tags: android, out-of-memory, multipartform-data, multipart, square

I'm trying to upload a large video file(100MB) to the server, but I'm getting OutOfMemoryError. Below works fine for small sizes files. What could be the issue for OutOfMemoryError?

```
        @Override
        public void writeTo(@NotNull BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
            Source source;
            source = Okio.source(file);
            try (Buffer buffer = new Buffer()) {
                long remaining = contentLength();
                long originalFileLength = contentLength();
                for (long readCount; (readCount = source.read(buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)) != -1; ) {
                    if (mMediaUploadService.isRetryShown())
                        break;
                    sink.write(buffer, readCount);
                    sink.flush();
                    fileSize = contentLength();
                    remainingBytes = remaining -= readCount;
                    LogMessage.d(TAG, "source size: " + contentLength() + " remaining bytes: " + (remainingBytes));

                    uploadTaskCompletedListener.onUploadProgressChanged(readCount, originalFileLength);
                }
                firstTimeCall[0] = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LogMessage.e(TAG, "write to exception: = " + e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                Util.closeQuietly(source);
            }
        }
```

for this code, I'm getting the below error

```
E/Logger: [RxSchedulerPurge-1(913): MobileApplication.kt:uncaughtException:78] - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available 
E/Logger: [OkHttp Dispatcher(962): MobileApplication.kt:uncaughtException:78] - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.mirrorfly.qa, PID: 17212
Theme: themes:{}
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: `DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` ??? Well what is the size? How should we know?

Comment: `remainingBytes` You are not using that variable. Or `remaining`